# Points are not showing up on 3.28 QGIS versions

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, point-in-polygon, snapping

When I used 2.18 QGIS version the points to snap are there. Points that I mentioned are the points where each polygon corner is and where you can snap new polygon. In versions 3 higher it doesn't show them anymore and I can't snap the new polygon to the existing polygon and it will overlap the existing one. I tried changing the settings and used vertex as default snapping type but still failed to see the points. Sample picture below. It shows when I am using the vertex tool but when I use the add polygon feature it doesn't. Image below shows it overlapped the other polygon.

[image]

Comment: I assume you changed the settings at  *project* > *snapping options*?  Did you make sure to set "avoid overlapping on active layers" and turned on "snapping on intersection" or "self-snapping"? These options worked for me, but some are turned off by default. I am using qgis 3.30 's Hertogenbosch.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works